# How do I get access token inside Node.JS Google Cloud function?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, authorization

I have a cloud function in Node.JS on Google Cloud, I need to make GET request to Google and it requires an auth token. Using `curl` you can generate one using `$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)`. But this doesn't work in Cloud instance so how I can generate one?

Some of the function:

```
exports.postTestResultsToSlack = functions.testLab
  .testMatrix()
  .onComplete(async testMatrix => {

    if (testMatrix.clientInfo.details['testType'] != 'regression') {
      // Not regression tests
      return null;
    }

    const { testMatrixId, outcomeSummary, resultStorage } = testMatrix;

    const projectID = "project-feat1"
    const executionID = resultStorage.toolResultsExecutionId
    const historyID = resultStorage.toolResultsHistoryId

    const historyRequest = await axios.get(`https://toolresults.googleapis.com/toolresults/v1beta3/projects/${projectID}/histories/${historyID}/executions/${executionID}/environments`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)`,
        'X-Goog-User-Project': projectID
      }
    });
```

Comment: Are you facing any error while doing this? If so, could you provide your error here?

Comment: ```Error: Request failed with status code 401```

Comment: Check out the [document](http://cloud/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_programmatically) on generating tokens programmatically using Nodejs. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting) speaks about the 401 error and its solution. Also I have found some threads similar to your issue, check out these once: [Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61677881), [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60265116), [Thread3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66428509)

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: Try this one: [Link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_programmatically)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After countless hours spent, I stumbled across the answer scrolling through auto complete suggestions. Google has documentation about authentication but none mention this what you need for Cloud Functions to make API requests:

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');

const auth = new GoogleAuth();
const token = await auth.getAccessToken()

const historyRequest = await axios.get(
`https://toolresults.googleapis.com/toolresults/v1beta3/projects/${projectID}/histories/${historyID}/executions/${executionID}/environments`, 
      {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          'X-Goog-User-Project': projectID
        }
    });
```

Comment: Note that you need to define the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable for this to work. Also, I had to give an explicit scopes string to the constructor `const auth = new GoogleAuth({scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'});` otherwise you get the following on .getAccessToken(): 400 Bad Request `{
      error: 'invalid_scope',
      error_description: 'Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.'
    }`

Comment: see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs or https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs for more

Answer (score 0):

Here was my final working code for google auth. Similar to the above, but with credentials as a base 64 environment variable.

```js
import {GoogleAuth} from 'google-auth-library';

function getGoogleCredentials() {
  const base64Data = process.env.BASE_64_CREDENTIALS!
  // Convert the base64 string back to a Buffer
  const bufferData = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64');

  // Convert the Buffer back to a JSON string
  const jsonData = bufferData.toString('utf-8');

  // Parse the JSON string to get the JavaScript object
  const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  return {
    private_key: jsonObject.private_key,
    client_email: jsonObject.client_email
  }
}

const auth = new GoogleAuth({
  scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
  credentials: getGoogleCredentials()
});
const token = await auth.getAccessToken()
```

I cannot for the life of me understand how google expects one to do this differently using any kind of automated deployment software.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but calling Google Translate API, to create a token you need to add scopes, and if you are using a service account, grant the service Usage Consumer role.

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');

const auth = new GoogleAuth({
  scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
});
const token = await auth.getAccessToken()

const body = {sourceLanguageCode: 'en',targetLanguageCode: 'ru',contents: ['Dr. Watson, come here!', 'Bring me some coffee!'],};

const request = await axios.post('https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/[project-id]:translateText', body, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 'x-goog-user-project': '[project-id]' },
  })
```