# Authenticate with Vertex AI generative AI API in cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to authenticate with the Vertex AI Generative AI API in my google cloud function. I can see that both have the same service account attached to them. So I thought that authentication will not be necessary since it would be done implicitly so I didn't include any authorization headers. However I'm getting a 401 error in my logs which indicates a lack of auth credentials. How do I get these auth credentials? I'm using the code below to communicate with the API:

```
const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    const chatparams = {
        instances: {
            context: "",
            examples: [],
            messages: [{
                "author": "user",
                "content": "how do i talk to you"
            }]
        },
        parameters: {
            temperature: 0.2,
            maxOutputTokens: maxtokens,
            topP: 0.8,
            topK: 40
        }

    };

    // eslint-disable-next-line promise/no-nesting
    return axios.create({headers}).post("https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectname/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/chat-bison@001:predict", chatparams).then(result => {
            return result.data;
        }
    ).catch(error => {
        console.log('error in getting data from chatgpt is ' + error);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69895524/2646187 You'll also need to implement the instructions in the comment below the answer that I linked.